# US: consumer remedy rights for product safety recall

Tags: united-states, consumer-protection

When a manufacturer issues a product safety recall in the US, are they obligated to provide a *useful* remedy?  Do I have any right to reject their proposed remedy and return the product to the retailer?  Does it make any difference if the product is still under warranty?

I just received a recall notice for an air conditioner that is probably out of warranty.  The manufacturer has offered to repair it, but their nearest authorized repair center is over 120 miles away.